# data and directory can not be found

Tags: database, import, terminal, directory, db2

Helo,
while trying to import a database in db2 using the terminal I get always this message:
-bash: cd: musterloesung_block1/: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdJDX.jpg)

Comment: You are trying to change into a directory (using the `cd ` command) that does not exist. Why do you think this is a programming question?

Comment: I know it is not programming question but its related issue. I must import the database in db2 in order to complete my project. there will be access later to this database and now I have a problem with the terminal.the steps given by the tutor as following:Schritt 1) Erzeugung der Datenbank: db2 "create database sharer"
-- Schritt 2) Verbindung zur Datenbank herstellen: db2 "connect to sharer"
-- Schritt 3) Importierung der Beispieldaten: db2 -vtf create_tables.sql

Comment: when I try to make the last step but by other way : I should write cd Musterlösung_block1/ then enter then /musterloesung_block1$ ls

Comment: This is more Linux question then Db2 question. If you need to change directory to Musterlösung_block1 then you need to type: cd Musterlösung_block1

Linux is case sensitive. You can also try: cd M and press <Tab> key and Linux will automatically find all directory names started with letter M. Then press Enter.